# DBMS_LOCK throwing error in procedure ie identifier must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I execute "dbms_lock.sleep", it runs successfully. However, when I put the it in a procedure then it throws error like 'identifier 'DBMS_LOCK must be declared''

```
exec dbms_lock.sleep ( 5 ); -- this is working 

create procedure p1
...
dbms_lock.sleep ( 5 ); -- Error(264,2): PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_LOCK' must be declared
...
end;
/
```

The below is from dba_objects:

```
SYS     DBMS_LOCK   PACKAGE BODY
SYS     DBMS_LOCK   PACKAGE
PUBLIC  DBMS_LOCK   SYNONYM
SYS     DBMS_OUTPUT PACKAGE
PUBLIC  DBMS_OUTPUT SYNONYM
SYS     DBMS_OUTPUT PACKAGE BODY
```

Answer (score 4):

Privileges obtained through a role are not effective inside a PL/SQL block. The `execute` privilege on the package needs to be granted to the user directly, e.g.:

```
grant execute on dbms_lock to your_oracle_user;
```

Comment: Do note that you still need to have sufficient privileges to execute the `grant execute`, in my case i have `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` (And i can't contact database administrator, for xxx reasons)